# How can i solve SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, jsp

> How can i solve this problem. please help me.
>   i have tried long time for solve this error. but i can't.

```
String mname=request.getParameter("m");
String imgurl=request.getParameter("imgurl");
String catocagory=request.getParameter("catocagory");
String[] s=new String[3];

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:BoxOffice","system","sa");
Statement st=con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs;
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from "+catocagory+"where name='"+mname+"'");
while(rs.next())
    {
        s[0]=rs.getString("c1");
        s[1]=rs.getString("c2");
        s[2]=rs.getString("c3");
    }
%>
```

Comment: If in doubt always print out the query and run against the database itself...

Comment: Stop using the JDBC/ODBC bridge. It is buggy, slow and unreliable. Plus it is no longer available in Java 8. Use the "native" JDBC driver from Oracle. And if you have changed all that, switch to using a `PreparedStatement` because you are wide open to SQL Injection. And finally use a connection pool and move those SQL statements into a servlet. Don't put SQL handling directly into a JSP page.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space in concatenating SQL, try this

```
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from " + catocagory + " where name='" + mname + "'");
```